# Minimization over a specific set

Tags: optimization, vector-spaces

Suppose we want to find the argmin of a function over a specific set:
\begin{equation}
\tilde z= \text{arg}\min_{z \in I} \Phi(z),
\end{equation}
where $z$ is a vector (say, $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$) and $\Phi$ is the augmented Lagrangian of a convex optimization problem.

Is the following a formally correct method?

1) I compute the gradient of the function and set it to zero:
\begin{equation}
\nabla \Phi(z) = 0
\end{equation}
This way I find some vectors  $z_0$ which satisfy the minimum request (but might not be in the desired set).

2) I'm actualy looking for a minimizer in $I$, so  I look for a vector $\tilde z$ which is in $I$ and is as close as possible to the minimizer $z_0$, i.e. I project $z_0$ on $I$ :
\begin{equation}
\tilde z = \text{arg} \min_{Z \in I} \Vert z - z_0 \Vert_2 = P_I(z_0),
\end{equation}

where $P_I(\cdot)$ means I am projecting the argument on $I$.

Is it a sound method? I read a paper in which all the passages above are "taken for granted", in the sense that the author goes directly from the argmin problem to the projection without explanations, so I wanted to know whether I got it right.
(The result I get is coherent with the result on the paper, but this does not mean I'm right...)

Comment: In general that won't work. Constrained optimization is way more complicated. You should start by looking into Lagrangian multiplier theorem.

Comment: Well, actually the function $\Phi$ I need to minimize over $z$ is the augmented Lagrangian of a convex minimization problem.
I know it's usually more complicated than this, I just hoped that in some cases it could be true (especially in this case, since the author just skipped any explanation)

Comment: then you should state all (relevant) assumptions